# what do the commas in (cl,:,k) in MATLAB do, when building a matrix

Tags: matlab

I know how to build a matrix within MATLAB but the example I am working on has is defined as

```
   a(cl,:,k)=x*ang;
```

cl, k, x and ang are already defined. I just wondered what the (cl,:,k) does, in particular the role of the commas?

Also, if I were to replicate this within Excel then how would I do so?

Answer (score 2):

- The comma `,` in `a(cl,:,k)` is to separate different dimensions of the matrix `a`.
- The colon `:` in `a(cl,:,k)` is to select all elements along this dimension (restricted by other dimensions), which is shorthand notation for `1:end`. In other words, all elements `a(cl, 1:end, k)` are selected, where `end` is the size of the second dimension of `a`.

For example:

```
a = zeros(2, 3); // 2x3 matrix with all elements are 0
a(1, :) = [1 2 3]; // <=> a(1,1:3)=[1 2 3]; assign all elements to the first row
```

then, `a` will be

```
 1     2     3
 0     0     0
```

Comment: So if it were a(5,:,10) then it would be 5 arrays of dimensions (5,6) (5,7) (5,8) (5,9) (5,10) ?

Comment: @user3190506 No. it will select all elements like (5,1,10), (5,2,10),  (5,3,10), ...

Comment: Okay, so the colon acts as a variable? Thanks for your help but what would the limit be? i.e. (5,1,10), (5,2,10), (5,3,10)....(5,x,10) what would x be?

Comment: @user3190506 The limits are determined by the size of this dimension. If a is (5, 3, 10), then they are just 3 elements, i.e. (5,1,10), (5,2,10), (5,3,10). Updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand. The value in MATLAB is simply just a colon, so how do I know what the size of the dimension is?

Comment: When you create a matrix, you already set its size. For example, `a=zeros(2,3)`, then `a` is a 2x3 matrix.

Comment: And you can use `[r, c] = size(a)` to get its size (rows/cols).

Comment: @herohuyongtao That may be a bit confusing for matrices with higher dimensionality like `a = rand(5,4,11)`, rather use `s =size(a)`. Now the size of the second dimension can be called as `s(2)`.

Comment: The working code I am investigating simply is a(cl,:,k)=x*tanbhelx+horz*(k-P)*Pb/P+horz*(cl-(L+1)/2)*Pb   so there is no size for the colon

Comment: @user3190506 `a` is first used here? I doubt. It should be created somewhere earlier.

Comment: @user3190506 If the variable a does not exist yet, or is not large enough yet, then the colon will enable the size that is neccesary. Try `clear,z(1,1,1,1,:,1,:,1)=rand(3,4); size(z)`. If you don't understand the colon, try the general explanation that can be found via `help :` or `doc colon` and just play around with it for a bit.

Comment: @user3190506 The size of that second dimension (the `:`) will get defined by the RHS of your assigment. So that whole long `x*tan...` business will create a row vector, it already has a size and this size will define the size of the second dimension of `a` iff `a` doesn't already exist

Answer (score 0):

The commas separate the indices along different axes of the elements of the multi dimensional array you want to access

`:` means `1:end` - here end will become the largest index possible along that axis

```
>> a = zeros(3,3,3)

a(:,:,1) =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0


a(:,:,2) =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0


a(:,:,3) =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0

>> a(1,:,1) = 1

a(:,:,1) =

     1     1     1
     0     0     0
     0     0     0


a(:,:,2) =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0


a(:,:,3) =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0

>> a(2,1:end,2) = 2

a(:,:,1) =

     1     1     1
     0     0     0
     0     0     0


a(:,:,2) =

     0     0     0
     2     2     2
     0     0     0


a(:,:,3) =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0

>> a(1,1,:) = 5

a(:,:,1) =

     5     1     1
     0     0     0
     0     0     0


a(:,:,2) =

     5     0     0
     2     2     2
     0     0     0


a(:,:,3) =

     5     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```